# Laravel ORM - filter by name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm newer to Laravel and trying to use ORM to filter my results. So in my database I have table one (Developers) and table two (Programs):

```
Developers
-------------------
ID.   | Name      |
------|------------
1     | Bluegreen |
2     | Dancer    |
3     | Martin    |
------|------------

Programs
-------------------------------------
id    | developer_id |   name       |
------|------------------------------
1     | 12           | Program Test |
2     | 3            | Capital      |
3     | 2            | Asus         |
4     | 2            | Rich         |
5     | 5            | Huna         |
------|------------------------------
```

I'm trying to filter by the Program name and my code is filtering by Developer name. I can easily do this in raw sql but I'm trying to learn ORM, for some reason it's like super difficult for me to learn.

Here's my code:

```
$query = $request->get('search');
$developers = Developer::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->with('programs')->get();
```

Comment: Use Relational  Eloquient query in laravel

Answer (score 0):

> You can simply do this in a closure function in laravel with relationships. This will filter your record on program name and also developer name.

```
$developers = Developer::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
              ->with(['programs' => function($filter) use ($request) { 
                 $filter->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
              }])->get();
```

> If you want to only filter by program name then you can do it in this way

```
$developers = Developer::with(['programs' => function($filter) use ($request) { 
                 $filter->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
              }])->get();
```

> You can also write a condition if `$request->search` is empty then return all data. If it is not empty then only return the filtered data. I am just simply doing it but you can optimize the query later.

```
if($request->search != '')
$developers = Developer::with(['programs' => function($filter) use ($request) { 
                 $filter->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
              }])->get();
else
$developers = Developer::with('programs')->get();
```

Comment: Used your filter by program names and it's bringing all the programs back, it's not filtering by the $query.

Comment: Have you created `programs` model inside `Develeper` model ?

Comment: see updated answer. it is filter not filer in my code. I had a typing mistake.

Comment: The results do have the filtered search results, but also have all the results without programs. Anyway to filter the results without programs and just return the results with the $request->search?

Comment: Yes, this is in developer model:

public function programs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Program');
    }

Comment: yes you can do that if the filter is present then you can write a condition to query for filter, if not then just show all result.

Comment: How do you write a condition to filter by? I'm new to ORM so not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work.

```
DB::table('developers')
        ->join('programs','developers.id','=','programs.developer_id')
        ->where('programs.name', 'like', '%'.'Capital'.'%')
        ->select('programs.*','developers.name')
        ->get();
```

Comment: He is trying to use ORM not simple joining. Although it is simple for him too.